# Unable to store dynamically store value in property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Ok, let me re-word the question to be more clear and ask exactly what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a web service that is selecting the top 10 articles from my DB(I am selecting the ID, Title, Body, Author, Date) and storing them in a list of objects(Each object has 5 items). I am then calling that web service and building my `GridView` with the returned list of objects. So at any one time, I could have any where from 1-10 GridViewItems(Tiles in my case) on my page(Depending on the amount of objects in my list).

In my experience with ASP.net, say for instance I am filling a dropdown from a query. Say my query returns 2 columns (ID, Name). I would set the `DataTextField` to **Name** and the `DataTextValue` to **ID**.

I am looking for that same functionality here. When I click the button that is being generated in each `GridViewItem`(Tile) I want to be able to pull the ID from that specific article. I know that I need to store that ID when I am binding the `GridView` so I can use it when I click the **Read more** button.

My end product is when the user clicks the **Read more** button for one of the 10 articles, it will take them to a detail page of that article that shows them the entire article body, etc. I will pull this information from my DB by the **article** **ID**. That is why it is so crucial for me to bind the **article ID** to each `GridViewItem` correctly so I can pull the value and use it later.

I will post below my code that I have on how I am building my Gridview, etc.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TileTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TitleBlock" Text="{Binding TitleView}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="BodyBlock" Text="{Binding BodyView}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="110" Width="280" Margin="10,0"></TextBlock>
            <Button x:Name="ReadMoreButton" Content="Read more" Click="btnOpenArticle_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="tileGrid" Background="LightGray">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <controls:PageHeader BackButtonVisibility="Collapsed" Content="News" Frame="{x:Bind Frame}">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Behaviors:EllipsisBehavior Visibility="Auto" />
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoPrivacy}" Label="Privacy" />
            <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoAbout}" Label="About" />
        </controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
    </controls:PageHeader>

    <GridView x:Name="tileGridView" Margin="12,60" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TileTemplate}">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>

        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid Background="#2A2A2A"
                                  Margin="5"
                                  Height="200"
                                  Width="300">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
 public async void ViewData()
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        List<GetTileDetails> TileList = new List<GetTileDetails>();

        var res = await client.ViewDetailsAsync();
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Count; i++)
        {
            TileList.Add(new GetTileDetails(res[i].TitleView, res[i].BodyView.Substring(0,170) + " ...", res[i].IDView));
        }
        tileGridView.ItemsSource = TileList;
    }

 public class GetTileDetails
    {
        public string TitleView { get; set; }
        public string BodyView { get; set; }
        public int IDView { get; set; }

        public GetTileDetails() { }
        public GetTileDetails(string myTitleView, string myBodyView, int myIDView)
        {
            this.TitleView = myTitleView;
            this.BodyView = myBodyView;
            this.IDView = myIDView
        }
    }
```

Comment: You used DataTemplate and Bindings, so why not get the value from the bound ViewModel?

Comment: Because these are dynamic textblocks. What I mean by that is the 3 elements in the stackpanel are being filled from a list of objects. The list could have 4 objects in it. When it has 4 objects in it, it will build 4 Gridviewitems with the 3 elements in the stackpanel inside of the Gridviewitems. So what I am really trying to accomplish is to pull the current title and body of the gridviewItem i click the "Read more" button in.

Comment: The best way to address this is to add a property to your view model (i.e. `TileTemplate`) and bind it to whatever `TextBlock` property you're trying to access. Then you are dealing with the view model instead of the UI directly. You can get the `TileTemplate` instance in a variety of ways, but based on the little bit of code you've shown here, most likely you can just retrieve the `DataContext` of `e.OriginalSource` (i.e. the `Button`). Please provide a [mcve] that shows clearly what you're doing, so that a good answer can be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Tag property which is present in all FrameworkElements as a wonderful data-store.

```
<Button ... Tag="{Binding ID}" Click="Btn_Click"></Button>
```

In the Click event handler, you can easily access the sender and access its Tag property.

Comment: So I would be able to access the tag property value inside the Btn_Click click event?

Comment: Of course. You every Row would be having a Button column and this Button will have its Tag property set in every Row. Simple !

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the calling that tag in my code behind?

Comment: @Code I am assuming you are trying to get ID in your btnOpenArticle_Click method. Do this :  int id = Int32.Parse(((Button)sender).Tag.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

What about, instead of using `Click`, binding the `Command` of your button to your viewmodel (via `ICommand`). You could then store the value of your `TileView` property.